# Name or id of Iframe in CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

I am trying to create a plugin for CKEditor. As ckeditor creates Iframe for each textarea we want to convert as rich text editor, I want to know the name or id of that iframe.
How would I get it.

Help will be appreciated.

Regards

Parminder

Comment: +1 @Parminder ... have you got the solution already?

Comment: @Kyaw thurein, not yet. I couldnt find anything yet. feeling to goto mceeditor.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Firebug you'll see that the iframe doesn't have an id or name. Instead you should get the `editor.document.$` and move from that point, for example `editor.document.$.defaultView.frameElement`

Comment: thanks AlfonsoML, but what is editor here. also what about if i have multiple instance of the editor on the page.

Comment: Editor is the instance of CKEditor that you want to handle. It's the parameter for the init method of your plugin